# (Samsung) Possibility to check bootloader status using PC

Tags: adb, bootloader

Is it possible to check bootloader status **using adb** of a samsung device back from 2014 or older?
(s5 and below) there's no fastboot, and no "OEM Unlock" in developer options
and since i need to get the info using pc

Do I need to program an android application to go with my desktop one to detect bootloader status?
If so, is it even possible to get bootloader status using an app?

**Context:**
I'm creating a desktop program which needs to determine bootloader status to do certain tasks. I have searched for ways to do it, i found 3 only, none work in my case

Using dialer to find it, I get no output at all..

Using fastboot, There's no fastboot, only download mode

Using an adb command, it helped but it did not output the bootloader status

Comment: Try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo&hl=en_AU) to see if it reveals bootloader status

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, but it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Samsung devices, if there is no OEM unlock in the Developer Settings, then the bootloader is unlocked by default. OEM lock is enabled on carriers models only.

Moreover Samsung devices don't have fastboot, they have a proprietary protocol instead.

Comment: thanks for the info... that's wierd because my phone is T-Mobile and doesn't have `OEM Unlock`.... _Anyway  So I guess i'll have to program my app to either check for the existence of that option in settings, or use fastboot if available_

Comment: Which variant model is your device? Check in `About device` options

Comment: SM-G900T .. it is T-Mobile  (kltetmo) (s5 lte (snapdragon) tmobile)

Comment: This variant has a locked bootloader I guess, like most T-MO devices

Comment: it is. because it blocked my first ever flashing try and bricked itself  ..i don't know how i unlocked it later... and I can't try again because it's unlocked forever

Comment: Maybe because you downgraded it to a build with an unlocked bootloader

Comment: I remember my first successful flash was the official update from 5.1.1 to 6.0.1 using odin (success because unmodified binaries)... so you're saying they made it unlocked in 6.0.1 update maybe... _I don't remember exactly when it became unlocked but this could be the case_